# Convert Html Form to Pdf along with radio buttons and checkbox in java code

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

`enter code here`I have a form with more than 100's of fields along with radio and check-box. What will be the best way to create PDF from it. I have used iText v5.2.1 but it just prints text only in PDF not any input field. Because iText does not pick any HTML form (radio buttons and checkbox input fields) or css.

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JavaScript Form Validation using a sample registration form</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content="example, JavaScript Form Validation, Sample registration form" />
      <meta name="description" content="This document is an example of JavaScript Form Validation using a sample registration form. " />
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='js-form-validation.css' type='text/css' />
      <script src="sample-registration-form-validation.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="document.registration.userid.focus();">
      <h1>Registration Form</h1>
      <p>Use tab keys to move from one input field to the next.</p>
      <form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">
         <ul>
            <li><label for="userid">User id:</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="userid" size="12" /></li>
            <li><label for="passid">Password:</label></li>
            <li><input type="password" name="passid" size="12" /></li>
            <li><label for="username">Name:</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="username" size="50" /></li>
            <li><label for="address">Address:</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="address" size="50" /></li>
            <li><label for="country">Country:</label></li>
            <li>
               <select name="country">
                  <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
                  <option value="AF">Australia</option>
                  <option value="AL">Canada</option>
                  <option value="DZ">India</option>
                  <option value="AS">Russia</option>
                  <option value="AD">USA</option>
               </select>
            </li>
            <li><label for="zip">ZIP Code:</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="zip" /></li>
            <li><label for="email">Email:</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></li>
            <li><label id="gender">Sex:</label></li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="msex" value="Male" /><span>Male</span></li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="fsex" value="Female" /><span>Female</span></li>
            <li><label>Language:</label></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en" checked /><span>English</span></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="nonen" value="noen" /><span>Non English</span></li>
            <li><label for="desc">About:</label></li>
            <li><textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
         </ul>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

App.java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
      // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new FileInputStream("main.html")); 
        //step 5
         document.close();

        System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to add your Java code and your html. Also add which version of iText you are using. Additionally, make sure that you use `XMLWorker`, not the deprecated `HTMLWorker`.

Comment: Itext5.2.1 version are using

Comment: Please upgrade to iText 5.5.10 and use `XMLWorker` in your code, not `HTMLWorker`. I have to repeat my initial comment: edit your question to add your Java code and your html.

Comment: Do you work any pdf generator in using java

Comment: Yes I work at a software company that makes a pdf generator for Java. It's called iText Software.